# Disable modify\delete JTextArea content (but not insert)

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have JTextArea component and I need to disable modify\delete current content in component by users. Users may only add\insert some text at the end, but setText method must work as usual.

tnx

Comment: disable modification of textfield ( setEnabled(false) )
then use keylistener to add text only at the end. Do not write code for  backspace, so that person cannot remove previous text

Comment: Gagan93 but what about caret and ctr-x\ctr-v ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you post an example of what you already have?

To clarify, if you want users to be unable to certain things, you may need to re-insert the original text manually. I'm unsure of the editor used by a JTextArea, but you could try overriding that.

Horrific code I'm coming up with on the spot incoming, you can probably do this much easier:

```
private static String mand = "mandatory.";
private static JTextArea test = new JTextArea(mand);

public static String getMand() {
return mand;
}

public static JTextArea getTest() {
return test;
}

public static void setMand(String mand2) {
mand = mand2;
}

public static void setTest(JTextArea test2) {
test = test2;
}

getTest().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if(getTest().getText().startsWith(getMand())) {
            System.out.println("good, text still present");
            setMand(test.getText());
        } else {
            getTest().setText(getMand());
        }
    }

});
```

**WARNING** :: if the user makes any mistakes in adding information to the `JTextArea`, the code will not allow the user to fix these mistakes.

Tested successfully under JDK (/JRE) 7.

Comment: Gorb yes, that exactly what I need, but I decided to use DocumentListener instead KeyListener, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I need to disable modify\delete current content in component by users.

```
textArea.setEditable( false );
```

> Users may only add\insert some text at the end, but setText method must work as usual.

You should have an "Add Text" button that will take text from a separate text field and then append the text to the Document using the `append(...)` method of the JTextArea.